# XPath selecting a node with some attribute value equals to some other node's attribute value

Tags: xpath

```
<grand id="grand">
  <parent>
    <child age="18" id="#not-grand"/>
    <child age="20" id="#grand"/> <!-- This is what I want to locate -->
  </parent>
</grand>
```

Can anybody tell me how to express for locating the second child?

This doesn't work...

```
"/grand/parent/child[@id=concat('#',/grand/@id)]/@age"
```

Thank you.

---

I'm sorry. The expression is OK. I found I got some problems in other area not the expression itself.

Comment: Your xpath works fine for me.

Comment: Same for me - [just tested it here](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx) and it selects the second child element.

Comment: Right... The expression is OK. I'm sorry. I've made some mistakes in the expression(namespace prefix) and the instance document. Thank you.

Answer (score 114):

This XPath is specific to the code snippet you've provided.  To select `<child>` with id as `#grand` you can write `//child[@id='#grand']`.

To get age `//child[@id='#grand']/@age`.

Comment: Thank you Vaman. It helped. I meant referring the expression('/grand/@id') for one time evaluation not the value('#grand') which should be evaluated first.

Comment: what if my XML has list of section with name attribute then how to select is as subDataSource? Example: 
````<section name="valuation"> <capital-value> some data </capital-value> <location> some data </location> </section> <section name="subject-property"> <address>72 Gordon Avenue</address> <postcode>HA7 3QS</postcode> <bedrooms>2</bedrooms> </section>````

Answer (score 35):

I think this is what you want:

```
/grand/parent/child[@id="#grand"]
```

Comment: Thank you MarcoS. I meant referring the expression('/grand/@id') for one time evaluation not the value('#grand') which should be evaluated first.

Comment: @jin-kwon: I see. So, you're XPath is just fine.