# Python Selenium Find Randomly Generated Element ID

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, find, element

I have looked a few solutions on this issue on stackoverflow. Although I cannot seem to find working solution.

1. There are ton of elements with the id prefix "ext-gen" so most of the answers I have seen will not work.

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="New Player Arrived" id="ext-gen1084">
```

I'm trying to find this element and then return its value with

```
get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: If you don't know the exact id of the element you're looking for, how will you know when you've found it?  Are you always looking for an `<input type="submit">` element?  Can there be more than one of those with an id prefix of `ext-gen`?

Comment: Well I'm using xpath to find some elements so I don't need the id. Although to answer your question this is the only element on this page that has a <code><input type="submit"></code>. I don't know how to find elements by input type. Plus the xpath includes it's randomized id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/103417/2834978 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055530/2834978

Comment: Sorry everyone, I've found a solution on my own using css selectors.

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to find a randomly generated element ID:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']")
```

Comment: This does not actually answer a question *"How to find element with random ID"* , but *"How to find Submit button"*