# xPath attribute equals operator not working as expected

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LevelOne>
    <LevelTwo>
        <LevelThree class="MyClass">
            <Property name="FirstName">hello</Property>
            <Property name="SecondName">bar</Property>
            <Property name="ThirdName">world</Property>
            <Property name="FourthName">foo</Property>
        </LevelThree>
    </LevelTwo>
</LevelOne>
```

When I run the following *xPath* query,

```
xpath my.xml //Property
```

Gives me the following results where all the  nodes are selected.
[image: Result of the first query]

Now, I want to select the  node where the **name** attribute of the  node is equal to **FirstName**.
I came up with following xPath query after going through some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055432/xpath-selecting-a-node-with-some-attribute-value-equals-to-some-other-nodes-att) on the internet.

```
xpath my.xml //Property[@name='FirstName']
```

And I end up getting the following result on both macOS and Ubuntu terminals.
[image: Result of the second query]

What am I possibly doing wrong here?

Comment: Your expression is fine. Probably just a quotation problem. Try `xpath my.xml "//Property[@name='FirstName']"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in @Robby Cornelissen's answer, the issue seems to be with the quotations. Wrapping the query inside quotations as follows solved the problem.

```
xpath my.xml "//Property[@name='FirstName']"
```